# Get value from jquery to django view

Tags: jquery, django

How to get a value of object and use it in Django Views?

I need to take the result of autocomplete search to filter in views in Django.
This is my search view:

```
def search_view(request):
q = request.GET['term']
print q
sc = []
users = Account.objects.filter(username__icontains=q)
for user in users:
    sc.append(account.username)
content_type = 'application/json"
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(new), content_type)
```

In templete the rosult is for example: user1. I want to take this value to another django views:

```
def another_view(request):
    Event.objects.filter(member = user1)
```

My jquery code is this:

```
$( "#acounts" ).autocomplete({
          source: "{% url 'search_view' %}",
          focus: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#acounts" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
              select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#accounts").val(ui.item.label );
            $( "#accounts-id").html( ui.item.label );
            return false;
```

and html:

```
  <input id="accounts">
  <p id="accounts-id"></p>
```

Comment: Can we see what you tried at the moment ?

Comment: BTW, you are using different type of quotes in this line - `content_type = 'application/json"`

Answer (score 0):

url.py

```
 url(r'^api/user/(?P<id_user>w+)/$', views.another_view,name="another_view"),
```

views.py

```
def another_view(request,id_user):
    Event.objects.filter(member = id_user)
    # do stuff
    # return stuff
```

jquery:

```
var yourTerm = "something";
$.get( "api/autocomplete/yourobject/" + yourTerm, function( users) {
    // users = for example: ["user1", "user2"]

    // could be get or post or whatever depending what you are trying to do
    $.get( "api/user/" + users[0], function( data ) {
         // data is what your view responds
    });

});
```

Comment: i've just update my question, I don't know if I good understand - the users is in my code "accounts"? And how can I get "user_id"? Is this "account_id"?

Comment: but when do you want to send the user to the view? do you want to send it for each autocompleted result, or you want to send it after the clients does any interaction? If you want to use the id you need to get it from your autocomplete function. Any data you want to use in javascript, you need to take it from your django view functions

Comment: I want to send it for each autocompleted result, to generate csv, like somebody first search user, the result is "user1" and then he click on "create_report_on_csv", which is result of another view

Comment: but if someone search `user` the result may be [user1,user2,user3,user4]. So do you want to send all of them to a view in a single call? please is very unclear what you are pretending to do and is very difficult to help. I'm spending a lot of time just guessing what you are pretending to do

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm writing about the last result, which is in select, when somebody choose from dropdown list [user1,user2,user3] user1. I update my code, the last result is show in <p> and this is the value I need to use in filter in another view

Comment: And where is the problem? just take that user and send it to the view the same way you did with your data to autocomplete.

Comment: The problem is how to the that user :(

Comment: "how to the that user" ? what do you mean?

Comment: how to take that user, sorry. How to take value 'user1' and write it in django views.